# Understanding notation of norm with three vertical lines

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, normed-spaces, operator-theory, banach-spaces

We usually denote a norm with the notation $||\cdot ||$. However I've seen someone write $|||\cdot|||$. Is this the same as $||\cdot||$?

For instance, I have readed a note regarding functional analysis. A lemma states:

**Lemma:** Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with identity $I$. Then there is a norm $|||\cdot|||$ on $A$, equivalent to the original norm, such that $(A,|||\cdot|||)$ is a unital Banach algebra with $|||I|||=1$.

I am just curious. Could we just write the lemma as e.g.

**Lemma:** Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with identity $I$. Then there is a norm $||\cdot||$ on $A$, equivalent to the original norm, such that $(A,||\cdot||)$ is a unital Banach algebra with $||I||=1$.

Comment: I would say $|| \cdot ||$ is the most common way of denoting a norm. Different authors can use whatever notation they wish, but yes $||| \cdot |||$, while unusual is the same thing. Perhaps they were using $||| \cdot |||$ to distinguish between two different norms that a space can be endowed with.

Comment: Yes I agree on that. It is the first time I've seeing that kind of notation. 
Then I will read the notation as I am used to do so with the regular notation of norm.

However since the norm $|||\cdot|||$ is equivalent to the original norm, then I could litteraly write $||\cdot||$ instead?

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying - not quite. Let me write out some thoughts as an answer.

Comment: The answer to your post is "yes", and to your last comment is "yes, except if the notation $\|\cdot\|$ is already used for the original norm". But you can use any other notation than $||| \cdot |||$ for the new norm, such as $\|\cdot\|'.$ Note also that in other contexts, the notation $||| \cdot |||$ is dedicated to the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first, when we say something like let "$A$ be a Banach Algebra", we are implicitly assuming that there is a norm $||\cdot||$ defined on $A$ (after all, a Banach Algebra, by definition, is a type of normed space). The lemma which you have stated is saying something different. It might be the case that even though $|| \cdot ||$ is a norm, that $ ||I|| \neq 1$ with the norm $A$ has been endowed with. However, what the lemma is saying is that there exists a *different* norm, which they are denoting by $|||\cdot|||$, on $A$ such that $||| I ||| = 1$. They are stating this different norm is **equivalent** to the original norm $|| \cdot ||$ that $A$ was endowed with. The two norms are equivalent but they are not necessarily the same. Two norms $p$ and $q$ on a vector space $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) are **equivalent** if there exists real numbers $c, C >0$ such that $$cq(x) \leq p(x) \leq Cq(x) \  \text{for all} \ x \in X$$

Comment: (+1) I learn something new every day. Thank you for this nice explanation!
I will go with the notation as Anne mentioned since this is more intuitive than just $|||\cdot|||$.